# Why won't this jQuery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function (){
$("#kep").click(function (){
    $("#pic").fadeOut('slow', function (){
        $("#pic").html('<img src="y.jpg">', function (){
            $("#pic").fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
  });
});
</script>
<div id="pic">
 <center><img id="kep" src="x.jpg"></center>
</div>
```

It's annoying, I don't know why do I fail at these so hard. >.<

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is not happening ?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the browser?

Comment: what is the issue? show some jsfiddle

Comment: does `.html()` allow for a callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#kep").click(function() {
        $("#pic").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this) // point to #pic
                  .html('<img src="y.jpg">ddd') // append image to #pic
                  .fadeIn('fast'); // make fadeIn #pic
        });
    });
});
```

**Error in your code:**

```
 $("#pic").html('<img src="y.jpg">', 
       function (){
         // within this callback you are trying to make fadeIn()
         // which is not possible
         // this callback is to process the innerHTML of 
         // #pic, not the #pic itself
            $("#pic").fadeIn('fast');
        }
);
```

Comment: It's working thx, gonna mark as answer, but may you write an explanation why mine didn't work? :\

Comment: Kay, gonna mark as answer as soon as I can. :D

Comment: @SevenofNine check my update post, hope this will help you get your answer